# App crashing on playing a sound on button click method

Tags: iphone

I used uibuttons to create a grid view, now need to select and  deselect the button on its click.
All is working fine but when I try to play a sound on a button click, app get crashed by printing the below message in console:

`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIButton prepareToPlay]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7526a20'`

To play the sound,I have taken the object of AVAudioPlayer claas in .h file and initializing it in view did load method and playing it on button click, here is my code
.h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVAudioPlayer.h>
#import <AudioUnit/AudioUnit.h>

@interface PlayViewController : UIViewController<AVAudioPlayerDelegate>
{
    IBOutlet UIButton *resetBtn;
    UIButton *btn[25];
    AVAudioPlayer *tapSound;

}
-(IBAction)reserBtnClkd;
@property(nonatomic,retain) AVAudioPlayer *tapSound;

@end
in .m file
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"]]];
     NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    NSString *path=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"button-3" ofType:@"wav"];
    AVAudioPlayer *Tapsound=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
    self.tapSound=Tapsound;
    [Tapsound release];
    [pool release];
    [self setTheIcons];
    resetBtn.layer.cornerRadius=6.0;
    resetBtn.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:90/255.00 green:33.00/255.00 blue:179.00/255.00 alpha:1];
    resetBtn.titleLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:22];
    [resetBtn setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}

#pragma mark
#pragma mark<Creating The Grid View Of Icons>
#pragma mark

-(void) setTheIcons
{
    int x=11;
    int y=55;

    for(int i=1;i<=25;i++)
    {
        btn[i]=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        btn[i].frame=CGRectMake(x, y, 58,58);
        [btn[i] addTarget:self action:@selector(btnClkd:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [self.view addSubview:btn[i]];

        if(i%5==0)
        {
            x=11;
            y=y+60;
        }
        else
        {
            x=x+60;
        }
    }
    [self reserBtnClkd];
}

-(void)btnClkd:(UIButton*)sender
{
    sender.selected=!sender.selected;

    if(sender.selected)
    {
       // UIView *tempView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12, 12, 34, 34)];
        UIView *tempView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 58, 58)];
        tempView.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"hover-effectNew.png"]];
        tempView.userInteractionEnabled=NO;
        [sender addSubview:tempView];
        [tempView release];
    }
    else
    {
        NSArray *subviewToRemove=[sender subviews];
        int i=1;
        for(UIView *view in subviewToRemove)
        {
            if(i==2)
            {
            [view removeFromSuperview];
            }
            i++;
        }
    }
    [self.tapSound prepareToPlay];
    [self.tapSound setDelegate:self];
    [self.tapSound play];

}
```

And the strange thing is that App crashed only when I play the sound on button click method, otherwise if I play it in view did load then it works without any issue, Scratching my head for two days but could not find any solution, please help me

Comment: Why are you creating an autorelease pool there?

Comment: I had posted this question two days before also, so some one on stack overflow suggested me to do, earlier I was not using the autorelease pool, but it does not make any difference, get the same result

Comment: Why you declared two `tapSound` times @property(nonatomic,retain) AVAudioPlayer *tapSound; is enough and after this be sure it should be synthesized in your `viewController.m` class

Comment: I have synthesized it .m, but even if we dont set its property or whatever we do, app get crashed when button is clicked and a sound object is played in its touchup inside method which is initialized in view did load, you can try yourself and see that

Comment: Strange. What's the implementation of `reserBtnClkd`?

Comment: its just to change the images on each buttons, nothing to do anything with sound and button click

Comment: debug for self.tapSound, whether it is nil or not

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is that your `self.tapSound` is an `UIButton`(you can see it in the crash log: `'-[UIButton prepareToPlay]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7526a20'`.

Try debugging it step by step and see what happens

Answer (score 0):

I think because `self.tapSound`is referencing `Tapsound`, when you call `[Tapsound release]` it releases the property as well.  I would recommend instantiating the property directly, like this:

```
/*note that you have declared tapSound in your .h 
as a class variable in addition to being a property.
This means you can access it as both.
Wherever you would type self.tapSound, instead use simply tapSound
*/

tapSound = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
```

Comment: Try doing some NSLog's.  I assume you have verified that the line where the exception is thrown is [self.tapSound play]?  Also, perhaps try removing the setDelegate: line?

Comment: yep, done, it executes normally and when control goes to the line [self.tapSound play], it gets crashed

Comment: I tried to compile it, but you have not posted enough code for that.  Also, on further inspection, there are many weird spots in your code.  I would recommned these changes:

Comment: 1. update to ARC  2. instantiate the property directly, make sure you are @synthesizing it, and refer to it as the class variable  3. call [tapSound setDelegate:] and [tapSound prepareToPlay] in your viewDidLoad, you should only need to call [tapSound play] in the button function  4. resetBtn.layer.cornerRadius gave me an error, but I guess you must have a subclass or something.  Also, you are using for as a while loop, although it appears to work the same when used in this way.